# How to limit the volume of sound effects in Finder?

Tags: mac, finder, sound-volume

Sometimes I have my mac on full volume (maybe because I am / was listening to a song). Then I move a file in finder, or put something in the trash; finder plays the "move file" sound at full volume and it breaks my eardrums :D

Is there a way to limit the volume of sound effects on finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **System Preferences** > **Sound** > **Sound Effects** ... set **Alert volume** to the level you want.

This will also control the volume of the event sounds played in **Finder**.

You can also uncheck **[] Play user interface sound effects** to not have them play at all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this kinda helps.

To turn off sounds:

Go to System Preferences

Click on Sound

Uncheck "Play user interface sound effects"

[image: da cool screenshot]

Now **no** sounds will play from Finder

But you'll still get those "error" sounds when you type things that are not supported by the app (eg. Funk, Basso sounds)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The key was actually modifying the alert volume slider, in the same page you pointed to :)